# How to use igraph to plot two vertices by using non zero-based ID?

Tags: python, igraph

Hello I am new to igraph.

I'm trying to visualize a graph by using python module igraph. 
The graph G is output of a Karger min-cut, so it always has only 2 vertices.

The problem with igraph so far in my case is, I can only define the vertices ID in the edges as zero-based number (0, 1, ...). Cmiiw.

While the output of the Karger min-cut is randomly numbered vertices. 
Say that the input of the Karger min-cut is graph with 300 vertices with IDs = 0..299, then the output graph has two vertices with random IDs numbered 0..299.

E.g. the graph G (as input to the igraph) has edges = [(124, 207), (207, 124)]. 
If I try to plot the G,

```
>>> import igraph
>>> edges = [(124, 207), (207, 124)]
>>> g = igraph.Graph(edges=edges, directed=False)
>>> layout = g.layout("kk")
>>> igraph.plot(g, layout=layout)
```

then the resulting plot has 207 vertices, not the only 2 vertices as expected, as it should be [(0,1), (1,0)], that's zero based vertices.

How to use igraph so that I can plot two vertices by using non zero-based ID?

Thank you very much.

**Update**: I have solved my problem, as suggested by @Gabor Csardi in the comment, this way,

```
>>> g = igraph.Graph()
>>> g.add_vertices(2)
>>> g.vs["name"] = ["124", "207"]
>>> edges = [("124", "207"), ("207", "124")]
>>> g.add_edges(edges)
>>> layout = g.layout("kk")
>>> igraph.plot(g, layout=layout)
```

However, if there is better solution please answer, thank you.

Comment: Use symbolic names instead of ids. Ie. `[('124', '207'), ('207', '124')]`

Comment: Thank you @Gabor Csardi, I've tried to search references about symbolic name in the python-igraph tutorial webpage and reference webpage, also using google, but not found any clue on how to use symbolic name. WHen I tried to change it, I got error, "TypeError: only numbers, vertex names or igraph.Vertex objects can be converted
to vertex IDs". Would you mind to please elaborate more on how to define edges using symbolic name? Thank you.

Comment: Hi @Gabor Csardi, I have solved my problem, I forgot to define the add_vertices(). Thank you very much.

Comment: I have no idea what you are saying, but if the problem is solved, that is good. :)

Comment: Seems like the problem is solved, but I thought I'd chime in anyway: there is a wonderful method called `Graph.Formula` which lets you create such small graphs in a much nicer way: `g = igraph.Graph.Formula("124-207, 207-124")`.

Comment: Thank you very much Tamás, for the info. I'll try it soon. Update: Yes I found it much nicer, and I need only to remove one default edge. I am newbie, not sure how to mark the comments above as answers?